# In the Below snippet why the first function will be called not the second one, and is this the example of object overriding?

Tags: java, function, jvm, call

In the Below snippet why the first function will be called not the second one, and is this the example of object overriding?

```
package co.site;

public class Inheritance {

    void test(String str)
    {
        System.out.println(str +  "this is fro the functiokn 1 ");
    }
    void test(Object str)
    {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Inheritance in=new Inheritance();
        in.test("hello");   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding occurs when you inherit from a class and re-implement one of its methods. This is an example of **overloading** - having methods with the same name but different arguments. Here, `String` is a better match to `"hello"` than `Object`, so `test(String)` is called.

Comment: But is there any priority or structure that JVM knows that it will take on the string not the test(object), or there is any oops concept here which i am not applying?

Comment: @SubhamSinghRathor your code does not have to do anything with OOP yet. OOP is not restricted to creating an Object.

Comment: @SubhamSinghRathor The way the compiler resolves which method to use is [defined by the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). In layman's words, the more "specific" type (String) will be preferred over the base class `Object`.